# Requesting assistance with node drain and pod eviction in my Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I have a deployment with a single replica and a pod disruption budget with minAvailable=1.  When I drain the node, the pod does not evict (it is expected and needed) but the node drain process does not schedule the pod on another node. I am looking for a solution so that **when I drain the node, the pod should be first scheduled on another node, then should be evicted. **
As such affinity is not a requirement, but increasing replica is a requirement, so I can not increase any replica.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, best practices, or configuration recommendations from the community to achieve this desired behavior in my Kubernetes deployment.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What you are seeing is the expected behaviour. you will be getting error such as **Cannot evict pod as it would violate the pod's disruption budget**. For example, a PDB policy can define that there should always be two Pods available in the system (.spec.minAvailable is 2). But if you only have two Pods, and you try to remove the node containing one of them, then the PDB policy takes effect and prevents the removal of the node. If you can't increase the number of replicas, then remove the PDB attached to the deployment

Comment: What I want is that, even there is PDB, it should not drain the node completely, but instead first it should create the pod on another node and then it should start terminating the current one. this way even PDB would be satisfied.